# Splitting feature class by unique values for an attribute/field in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, splitting, split-by-attribute

I would like to split a single shapefile into multiple shapefiles by using unique values for one attribute/field to select features for each value out into a new feature class.

I found ET Geowizard to do this but it's not free.

In [arcscripts.esri.com](http://arcscripts.esri.com/) I found a tool named "SplitLayerByAttributes" but it does not work in ArcMap . (see comments below, this was an old version which has been updated.  The new version can be found at [resources.arcgis.com](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=37AEB018-1422-2418-A036-CA6D9920F808)   )

Do you know of any tools or solution to split by attribute in the way described above?