# Breaking apart a polygon layer by unique values, creating many new layers

Tags: raster, polygon, select-by-attribute

I have a large dataset of habitat information that I need to calculate distances from animal locations to the closest polygon of each habitat type. The way to do this, that I understand, would be to create Euclidean distance rasters for each habitat type. But in order to do this I need to break apart the original layer into many different parts. I can do this by "Select by attribute" and create a new layer for each one, but I was wondering if there was a tool that automates that and breaks apart a layer into multiple smaller layers by unique values in a column. If not, oh well, I'll get down to selectin' and creatin'.

Thanks in advance.

Ayden

Comment: Possible duplicate:[http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44410/how-can-i-split-by-attribute-in-arcgis-10/44435#44435](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44410/how-can-i-split-by-attribute-in-arcgis-10/44435#44435)

Comment: It looks like its asking the same thing yeah. Not sure if I saw it or not, may have not scrolled down far enough past the Python script (which terrifies me, pretty new to all this) and missed the answers that I could have understood. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Don't be terrified by the python code, its a lot simpler than it looks (trust me, I'm not a very experienced programmer myself).

Comment: Hah, alright, thanks for the motivation. I'll have to spend a little time working around with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `Feature Selection` iterator in ModelBuilder. You can specify the field you want the selection to be grouped by (your field containing the unique values). It will iterate over your entire feature class, creating a selection layer from each unique value. You can then add more tools for the rest of your workflow.

[image]

Comment: This works like a charm. However, I'm really new to the Model Builder and I can't figure out how to get the Euclidean distance rasters to save themselves as unique path names and not get rewritten when the next one is created. If not, thanks a bunch for the help.

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, you will need to use inline variables to ensure a unique output for each raster. Using the iterator's inbuilt variable `Value` (containing the name of the current input), you can set the path for all your outputs uniquely, e.g. for the output allocation raster you can put `C:\Documents\Allocation_raster_%Value%`, and for the distance raster you would put `C:\Documents\Distance_raster_%Value%`.

Answer (score 8):

Iterators would definitely help you here. Just in case you would need to export the feature classes on disk first, I attach the image I've created recently.

[image: an example of splitting the roads feature class into multiple ones based on roadtype field]

In case you don't want to bother with the model building, consider using [Split by Attributes tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=37AEB018-1422-2418-A036-CA6D9920F808) already compiled and available for use as a GP tool that does exactly the same thing as the model above.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. I had to give the green checkmark to Arabella because they posted first, but this works perfectly too. The additional advice on how to export the feature class was great. I am having an issue exporting the created Raster from Arabella's suggestion for Euclidean distance. They keep being overwritten when a new one is created. Any ideas? If not, no worries, thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Ah, no worries :) To avoid overwriting, I would also go for the Arabella's idea with inline variable substitution (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_using_inline_variable_substitution/002w0000001t000000/), it seems to be the best.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the link. Worked like a charm.