# Using a Select By Location in Python and Calculating a field based on what State Plane a point falls in

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system

Here's what I have so far.  Do I need to make another feature layer based on the selection?

```
import arcpy

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"PATH TO THE POINT", "point_lyr")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"PATH OF THE STATEPLANE", "stPlane_lyr")

arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("point_lyr", "INTERSECT", "stPlane_lyr")
```

Here's the updated Script for each state plane zone

```
 #Feature layers
 Point_Layer = "Point_Layer"
 CP_Layer = "CP_Layer"
 IntersectLayerCON = "IntersectLayerCON"

 # Process: Make Feature Layer for the SMON Points
 arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(SMONPoint, Point_Layer, "", "", "FID FID VISIBLE     NONE;Shape Shape VISIBLE NONE;link_fld link_fld VISIBLE NONE;State State VISIBLE NONE")
 # Process: Make Feature Layer for the Control Points
 arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(ControlPoint, CP_Layer, "", "", "FID FID VISIBLE NONE;Shape Shape VISIBLE NONE;link_fld link_fld VISIBLE NONE;State State VISIBLE NONE")
 # Process: Make Feature Layer for Intersection Shapefiles
 arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(IntersectLayer, IntersectLayerCON, "", "", "FID FID     VISIBLE NONE;Shape Shape VISIBLE NONE;OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;ZONE ZONE VISIBLE NONE;ZONENAME ZONENAME VISIBLE NONE;FIPSZONE FIPSZONE VISIBLE NONE;SQMI SQMI VISIBLE NONE;COLORMAP COLORMAP VISIBLE NONE;Shape_Leng Shape_Leng VISIBLE NONE;Shape_Area Shape_Area VISIBLE NONE")

 #This will calculate the fields labeled the correct STATE PLANE zone
 # Process: Select Layer By Location for SMON
 arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(Point_Layer, "INTERSECT", IntersectLayerCON, "", "NEW_SELECTION")
 # Process: Calculate Field for SMON
 arcpy.CalculateField_management(Point_Layer, "StatePlane", "\"Colorado North\"", "VB", "")
 arcpy.CalculateField_management(Point_Layer, "State", "\"Colorado\"", "VB", "")
```

It will just calculate the fields for state and state plane.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the question? I am not exactly sure what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to calc a field in my point feature class based off of what state plane zone it falls into which is a different feature class.

Comment: So, say you have 10 points in a fc (PointFC), 10 polygon fcs (each for each state plane zone) (StateZoneX) and then one reference polygon fc (AssignPoly). You take first point, check its location > say it is located within feature polygon in AssignPoly named StateZone1. Then you append this point feature to the feature class StateZone1. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes, I ended up just exporting the state plane zones into seperate shapes

Comment: I've posted an answer just in case you want to improve your code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can develop this workflow in either ModelBuilder or by using ArcPy.

ModelBuilder: you can refer to this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49583/breaking-apart-a-polygon-layer-by-unique-values-creating-many-new-layers/49609#49609) to see an example of model which you need to create. You basically have to make multiple selections on points and then export those feature layers into new feature classes. An [Iterate Feature Selection iterator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00400000000s000000) would help here.

Python: basically the same workflow and it might be actually more concise code-wise. I would get first unique values of state planes you have in your feature class.

```
def unique_values(table, field):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
        return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})
```

then iterate over the list and use each state plane name value as input for a selection expression. The resulting selection feature layer will be used to create a new feature class on disk (use [Copy Features GP tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000035000000) for that).