# Filtering out a subpart of a polygon shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, shapefile, polygon

I have ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop software.

I am working with a polygon shapefile (having n rows) in ArcMap. The project demands splitting this file into two polygon shapefiles having n1 and n2 rows such that n1+n2=n.

I can filter out the data using a where statement on the attribute table, but the resultant data does not have the field called "Shape", due to which I cannot plot the polygons.

I am new to ArcMap software.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44410/splitting-feature-class-by-attribute-in-arcgis-for-desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost the whole process.

After selecting the features you want to have in a separate shapefile (so that they are colored like in the picture), right-click the layer in Table of contents (the list to the left), --> Data --> Export data. Choose where to save the file.

To save the rest to a different shapefile, use the highlighted button (`switch selection`) and repeat the procedure.

This should give you two new shapefiles that together contain all your data.

[image]